# How to display multiple images with uploaded file URL's?

Tags: reactjs, image, heroku

I am working on a project that uploads images to Heroku with their new react-simple-file-upload addon. After uploading the file, a URL is provided for the image saved in the DB. I managed to display one of the images, but now I would like to display multiple-- essentially create a simple gallery. I am thinking i'll have to make a function that uses useState and an array, but am not really sure how to design it beyond that. Here is my working code:

```
import React from "react";
import SimpleFileUpload, { SimpleFileUploadProvider } from "../components/SimpleFileUpload"
import { useState } from 'react'
import "./styles.css"

const API_KEY = '...'


export default function About() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState();
  console.log(files)
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>upload an image</h1>
      <SimpleFileUpload apiKey={API_KEY} onSuccess={setFiles} />
      {files && (
        <div>
          <img className="photo" src={files} witdh="50" hight="50" alt="huh?"/>
          <div className="gallery">
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any tips or tricks is greatly appreciated

Comment: if `files` is an array of URLs (partial or absolute) then you should be able to use the array `map` function to render out a view for each entry in the array. i.e. `files.map((file, index) => <img key={index} src={file} />)`. Note: any react components contained in an array (just the root component at each index) will need a key that allows react to identify the component, usually this should be something unique to each entry in the array, in case the array is reordered or an item is removed, and not just the index.

Comment: @JacobSmit Unfortunately ```files``` is a string only containing the 1 URL of the image uploaded, which is why I am confused. I'm guessing I need to then make a useState array that contains a list of all of the URL's uploaded? But am just not sure how to do that

Comment: Well you already are using `useState` and using arrays with it is not much different, you just need to remember that you should create new arrays when setting the state and not mutate the existing state. i.e. for an add `setFiles([...files, newFile])` or for a removal `setFiles(files.filter(f => f != fileToRemove))`. You will then need to incorporate the logic to handle these updates into your components to allow for adding / removing of files from your array.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. How does the array retain the information array refresh? I have to use local storage?

Comment: On refresh? Well that has a number of solutions you could use local/session storage (session might be more appropriate in this case?). If the user is currently logged in you could use the server to keep track of it what the user has uploaded but not finalised. There is also any of the available Web DBs i.e. IndexDb. I guess with out having a full picture of what the solution is required to do it's hard to make a recommendation, but you should be able to quickly get a session or local storage implementation set up to test out and investigate other options if required.

Comment: I made a quick example of arrays and useState that you can take a look at if you think it could help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kgfyox

Comment: @JacobSmit Thank you so much for this! Hugely helpful. I'm finally understanding these concepts better!